# Recursive puzzle

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to run a recursive function for the next assignment:

I have a Boolean board with nXn columns and rows.

I want to search for a TRUE value on the diagonal lines (which are ↖ ↗ ↘ ↙) from a certain points specified by "row" and "col"

When I find a TRUE value in the specific line - I'm adding it to a counter, and stop looking in the specific line.

I want to return the number of TRUE values in the diagonal lines (minimun = 0 - maximun = 4)

F  F  T  F

F **T** F F

F F F F

F F F T

for example, the search point is **T** {1,1}. I need to return back the number 2.

```
public static int Cross (boolean[][] board, int row, int col, int row2, int col2){ //function to check Cross Threat
    int countCross=0;
    if(row2>=board.length | row2<0 | col2>=board.length | col2<0) //out of bounds - 0
        countCross=0;
    else if(board[row2][col2] & (row2!=row & col2!=col)) 
        countCross=1;
    else
        countCross=Cross(board, row, col, row2+1, col2+1)+Cross(board, row, col, row2-1, col2-1)+Cross(board, row, col, row2+1, col2-1)+Cross(board, row, col,row2-1, col2+1);
    return countCross;
}
```

The problem is that wheb i run this function, my Eclipse freezes.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clarify why 2 is the expected result for this input?

Comment: Your code is not recursive.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're asking.  What are the "crosses" you speak of?  Which one is "the closest cell" - closest to what?  What does the `CrossThrt` method do?  I'm voting to close this question as unclear, but I'll remove my close vote if you can fix it up.

Comment: Tried to make it more clear.

Comment: Your question is still not clear. `CrossThrt(...)` still has not been included. There's still no explanation as to why T{1,1} should return 2.

Comment: Sorry my bad. CrossThrt = Cross (changed the name and forgot to change all).

Comment: So what's the actual question?

Comment: @OmerLux I think you'd benefit from also focusing on bitwise vs. logical use of `and` and `or` (`&`, `&&`, `|`, `||`).

Comment: @phatfingers with `boolean`s, they're both logical. One is short-circuiting and one isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You need to incorporate direction into your Cross method (your method names should start with lower-cased letters).  Otherwise, your recursive calls will also try to go in four different directions.  One approach could be to create a public method that is non-recursive that calls a private recursive method once per direction.

Comment: Got it! Thabk you!